# What are the different commands available for nuget package manager console?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone post the different commands available in package manager console for visual studio.

examples:

```
install-package packagename
remove-package packagename
```

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference - Package Manager Console Powershell Reference

Comment: Did you try anything? Seriously, when you open the package manager console window it says how to do this. `get-help nuget`.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) documentation from MS enlists all the commands that you can run on Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [nuget command line reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference).

Comment: @ downvoter, what did you expect me to answer?

Comment: thanks justin i was thinking of something advance like you can do with ruby

Comment: @Justin: I didn't downvote, but for your future reference, this is the kind of question that should be closed as not constructive. If the answer to the question is a link to the documentation, then the link can be provided in a comment and the question closed.

Comment: Your link points to nuget.exe CLI reference while OP has asked about Package Manager Console commands which is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console). It is available on the very same page. You might want to fix it.